# Updating content of In-App Purchase Apple-Hosted (iTunes Connect)

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I have an app that is already on the App Store, the App contains In-App Purchases that area already available for download, I want to update this In-App purchases.
In the Itunes connect portal I can *add a new version of the app* but I don't see anything similar in the *In App Purchases* section.

How can I update the content? I have checked the documentation and it appears that I have to upload a new App version but that's not clear for me.

Answer (score 1):

I use the Transporter tool to upload in-app purchases, and, in my case, all I have to do is to upload a new package with the same bundle ID, and it automatically associates the package to the existing one.

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Izv6r.png) is how the "in-app" gets after upload, with the previous version still available in the store and the new one ready to submit.